# sleeping awaiting command blocks other transactions

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, transactions, locking, sleep

I have a big web application on asp.net 2.0.
Usere open object editor there and makes some changes. They can not open the same object at one time.

After they press "save" btn all changes process to save on server via postback.

I am using transaction for save. There are a lot of procedures, checks and others to be done before saving operation is OK.

```
using (SqlConnection con = .........)
        {
            SqlTransaction trans = null;
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                trans=con.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted);
                ........operations.........
                trans.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                try { if (trans != null) trans.Rollback(); }
                catch { }
                throw new MyException("SQL Exception: " + e.Message, e);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (con != null && con.State == ConnectionState.Open) con.Close();
            }
        }
```

For me this code is quite safe.

But periodicaly happens:
one process from this web application on saving operation on mssql became "sleeping/awaiting".
and others processes called by other users became locked by this process and organiza a queue.

One of them threw timeout excetion.....but others are waiting.

So, my question is: does my code have some bad operation that allows command to became sleeping/awaiting?
May be there are some tricks?

Comment: You have obviously omitted code to shorten you code example, so it might be because of that, but I do not see a trans.Commit() call anywhere in your code?

Comment: What is the purpose of the empty catch block after `try { if (trans != null) trans.Rollback(); }`. Wondering if that is burying some error.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are doing a lot DB of operations inside a transaction there is a chance that a database lock is blocking your application.

You can use the sp_who2 stored procedure (there are more details on it [here](http://sqlserverplanet.com/dba/using-sp_who2/)) to see if there any blocks on your server, by checking the BlkBy column of the result.

You might also want to check the following links on [Sql Server locks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213039%28SQL.80%29.aspx?ppud=4) and [deadlocking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213040%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx?ppud=4)

Comment: Yes, there is a lot of DB operations. DB is very loaded. But why this commands are exists in DB. If DB wii lock my command, application with throw an exception and transaction will be rollbacked. It may be happens, but this command is still exists and others are waiting for it.

Comment: No exceptions are thrown on locks, except timeout exceptions if you've set a timeout on the command executing the transaction. Try using the sp_who2 stored procedure to see if indeed there are processes blocking each other in your database.

Comment: I have chacked that at last case - there were no deadlock. The 1-st command was sleeping/awaiting, the second was lock by 1-st, 3-rd - by 2-nd.........etc

Comment: Killing the number 1 process (using the kill command) does free all your other process and makes the pages load ?

Comment: i have no time to test this case? so we set a job that kill such commands for special user and application. Are there any more suggestions?

Comment: Sometimes sp_who2 will not correctly show you all the locks so chances are that you do have a deadlock. You will have to do additional debugging to be 100% sure and perform the necessary fixes. Alternatively, for the parts of your application where it is acceptable to read data from the intermediate stages of transactions, you can use the "Read Uncommited" isolation level.

Answer (score 0):

But the main problem is that the first process does not threw timeout exception. It is sleeping as log as we do not kill him. That is the main problem.

Answer (score 0):

Может ли это быть связано с репликацией. В момент когда наблюдаются описанные выше тормоза репликация начинает сильно тормозить. И пишет:
  The process could not connect to Publisher 'эта бд'. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number: MSSQL_REPL20084)
Get help: http://help/MSSQL_REPL20084

·          TCP Provider: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 10060)
Get help:
·          An error has occurred while establishing a connection to the server. When connecting to SQL Server 2005, this failure may be caused by the fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not allow remote connections. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 10060)
Get help: 
·          Login timeout expired (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 0)
Get help: 
·          The merge process failed to execute a query because the query timed out. If this failure continues, increase the query timeout for the process. When troubleshooting, restart the synchronization with verbose history logging and specify an output file to which to write. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number: 0)
Get help: 
Эта БД является источником репликации.